# How to find files in a directory using grep with wildcards?

Tags: unix, grep

I have several hundred files with file names such as:
     20110404_091415-R1-sometext

Another file name might be named:
     20110404_091415-R1.2-sometext

What I would like to do is use the Unix grep tool in the terminal to find files that start with 2011 and also contain -R1 within the file name.  Unfortunately, I have no idea to find files that satisfy both these criteria.  I have tried to figure out a regex that would match this, but I am only a beginner programmer.  Can anyone help please?  Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why even use grep? I think `ls 2011*R1*` should suffice..

Comment: it should be << ls 2011*-R1* >> without the quotes, and its an example of using a regular expression in grep.

Comment: thanks for pointing out..i've corrected it..this is what happens when you are out of touch with bash and start using powershell :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | grep "^2011.*-R1.*"
```

Should do the job

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is unreliable. Besides, this can be done using globbing.

Answer (score 0):

Just to find files, you can use `ls 2011*R1*` or `echo 2011*R1*`. To do something to files, use a loop (generally)

```
for file in 2011*R1*
do
   ....
done
```